# Permutation of n bernoulli random variables in R

Tags: r, permutation

I have a set of n variables, each of which can take a value of 0 or 1. I'd like to use R to get a matrix (or data frame etc it doesn't matter) that consists of all possible permutations of the n values. For example if n=3 the possible values are:

```
 111
 110
 101
 100
 010
 011
 001
 000
```

How could I do this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `expand.grid` to do it.

```
expand.grid(0:1,0:1,0:1)
```

**Output**:

```
   #   Var1 Var2 Var3
   # 1    0    0    0
   # 2    1    0    0
   # 3    0    1    0
   # 4    1    1    0
   # 5    0    0    1
   # 6    1    0    1
   # 7    0    1    1
   # 8    1    1    1
```

If you want to paste it as one item then you may choose:

```
do.call("paste0", expand.grid(0:1,0:1,0:1))
```

which would result in :

```
[1] "000" "100" "010" "110" "001" "101" "011"
[8] "111"
```

Also as suggested by @Jilber Urbina , one may use: `expand.grid(1:0,1:0,1:0)[3:1]` for a different order

**To generalise the solution:**

one can also do: `expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), 3))` , Here 3 is the no of repeats, so someone can change it to 20 or 100 basis their needs.

**Alternate method:**

```
gtools::permutations(n=2,r=3, v=0:1, repeats.allowed = T)
```

Comment: Maybe `expand.grid(1:0,1:0,1:0)[3:1]` to get the OP's desired output as he posted.

Comment: @JilberUrbina, Thanks, Updated

Comment: @PKumar Thanks, this works great. Is there a best way to do this for an arbitrary n? For instance if n=20 I'd like to not type out 0:1 twenty times.

Comment: @RobertMontgomery , yes there is, I am updating the answer

Comment: @RobertMontgomery, Added an alternate method as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, `crossing/unite` can also be useful

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(v1=0:1, v2=0:1, v3= 0:1) %>% 
              unite(v, names(.), sep="")
```